# Why Synchronization isn't working in the following Code?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, synchronized

This code sometime throwing an Exception even i have used  `synchronized` Method `removeFirst` within `synchronized` block of run method, I am adding and removing element on a `synchronizedList`.

```
public class NameDropper extends Thread {

    private NameList n1;

    public NameDropper(List list) {
        this.n1 = new NameList(list);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List l = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList());
        NameDropper n = new NameDropper(l);
        n.n1.add("Ozymandias");
        Thread[] t = new NameDropper[10];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            t[i - 1] = new NameDropper(l);
            t[i - 1].setName("T" + Integer.toString(i - 1));
            t[i - 1].start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                String name = n1.removeFirst();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": "
                    + name);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
}

class NameList {
    private List names = null;

    public NameList(List list) {
        this.names = list;
    }

    public synchronized void add(String name) {
        names.add(name);
    }

    public synchronized String removeFirst() {
        if (names.size() > 0)
            return (String) names.remove(0);
        else
            return null;
      }
}
```

The exception it is throwing:

```
T1: Ozymandias    
T2: null    
*Exception in thread "T3" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0    
    at java.util.LinkedList.entry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at NameList.removeFirst(NameDropper.java:57)*
T0: null    
T8: null    
*at NameDropper.run(NameDropper.java:33)*      
T6: null    
T4: null    
T9: null    
T7: null    
T5: null
```

Comment: If you are doing all your list access in synchronized methods, you don't need a synchronizedList. You don't risk any concurrent access to the structure, so the added synchronization just slows your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by other people, you have a race condition because all of your threads are synchronized on themselves. You need a common object to synchronize on.

I would recommend that you synchronize on the list itself. It will mean that any instances that are contending for the same list are blocked on each other and any threads that are not, will not be blocked. Your add and remove methods should be:

```
public void add(String name) {
    synchronized (name) {
        names.add(name);
    }
}

public String removeFirst() {
    synchronized (name) {
        if (names.size() > 0)
            return (String) names.remove(0);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're creating a new `NameDropper` instance for each thread.
Therefore, the `synchronized` methods aren't actually locking, since each instance is never used by two threads.

Comment: Right.  The recommendation is always to synchronize on a `final` object whose reference never changes.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are using `Collections.synchronizedList` there is a race condition that exists in your code.

Below is the example of the race codition inside your code.

```
lock(NameDropper[0])                            lock(NameDropper[1])
 names.size() > 0 is true                       names.size() > 0 is true  
                                                names.remove(0)
 names.remove(0) <--- Error here.
```

Since you are creating `NameDropper` instance for each thread  `which shares single instance of List` you have this race condition.

What you can do is create separate list for each `NameDropper`

```
        List l1 = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList());
        t[i - 1] = new NameDropper(l1);
```

This way each `NameDropper` will have its own instance of `List`.

Answer (score 1):

In general:
1) Since you are creating a new instance of your class each time, you basically have no "common" object for all threads to to lock upon. You should define something like:

```
static final Object lock = new Object();
```

and `synchronize` on this object instead.

2) IMHO it's preferable to implement `Runnable` rather than extending `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, NameList is not being shared. Here is one way with minimal recoding to fix your code (there are others):

Change the constructor to take a NameList (not List).

```
public NameDropper(NameList list) {
    this.n1 = list;
}
```

Create the NameList where you are currently creating the List.

```
NameList l = new NameList(Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList()));
```